# Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
<button id="'+item['id']+'" class="btnDeactivateKeyInChildPremiumCustomer waves-effect waves-light">ok</button>
```

I used above code for generating button inside of jquery each function.The button created dynamically and when i clicked the button , it should show the progress on the button.
Im using this [Ladda Button Loader](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda).

```
btnDeactivateKeyInChildPremiumCustomerClick : function(event){
   var id = event.currentTarget.id;
   var btnProgress = Ladda.create(document.querySelector('#'+id));
   // btnProgress.start(); or btnProgress.stop();
}
```

And then i passed the button the event handler catch the event process the above function.Inside that function it will create a **btnProgress** object.
After that i can call start() or stop() functions.I have successfully worked the in the case of only one button without creating the button dynamically inside each . But in the for each case it is showing some errors while executing **var btnProgress = Ladda.create(document.querySelector('#'+id));**

**Error**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#22' is not a valid selector.
```

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You are allowed to use [IDs that start with a digit](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) in your HTML5 documents:

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.
>
> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

But `querySelector` method uses CSS3 selectors for querying the DOM and CSS3 doesn't support ID selectors that start with a digit:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Use a value like `b22` for the ID attribute and your code will work.

Since you want to select an element by ID you can also use `.getElementById` method:

```
document.getElementById('22')
```

Comment: so in my case
var btnProgress = Ladda.create(document.getElementById('#'+id));

Comment: @boycod3 without the hash `var btnProgress = Ladda.create(document.getElementById(id));`

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `#` for the `getElementById` method. Just the ID.

Answer (score 93):

Although this is valid in HTML, you can't use an ID starting with an integer in *CSS selectors*.

As pointed out, you can use `getElementById` instead, but you can also still achieve the same with a `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector("[id='22']")
```

Comment: This solves even the rare case when id contains reserved characters like `[`,`]` (square brackets) or `:` (colon)