# Why is my CSS selector invalid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use the following database ID as a selector

```
5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3
```

The snippet is as follows:

```js
document.querySelector('#5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3')
```

```html
<button id="5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3">
```

When I try the selector, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3' is not a valid selector.
```

What is wrong with my selector?

Comment: An ID selector cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although this is valid in HTML, you can't use an ID starting with an integer in *CSS selectors*. You could use an attribute selector instead:

```
document.querySelector("[id='5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3']")
```

Or switch to using `getElementById` if that is an option:

```
document.getElementById("5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3")
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[id=5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: @Hoa Try the updated code, I forgot to quote the attribute value :)

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `document.getElementById('5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3')`

Comment: I would imagine `getElementById` would be faster than `querySelector("[id='']")` too.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to start an `ID` with a digit, but with `querySelector` you have to follow the `CSS` standards.

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit.

Use `document.getElementById("5b4bb7d2685cfb094b1d46c3")` instead.

**Reference:**

[Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270787/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-queryselector-on-document)

Answer (score 0):

QuerySelector method uses CSS3 selectors for querying the DOM and CSS3 doesn't support ID selectors that start with a digit.