# js querySelectorAll not a valid selector despite it being like the docs example

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

*Here, an attribute selector is used to return a list of the list items contained within a list whose ID is "userlist" which have a "data-active" attribute whose value is "1"*

```
var container = document.querySelector("#userlist");
var matches = container.querySelectorAll("li[data-active=1]");
```

but when i try

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id=7821549]');
```

i get:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'div[data-id=7821549]' is not a valid selector.
```

this is the div im trying to get:

```
<div class="cell cell--event-list cell--odds js-event js-event-odds js-event-odds-7821549 js-event-status-finished" data-id="7821549">
```

Comment: I just fixed the MDN page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example selector `"li[data-active=1]"` throws a similar error on my Chromium browser as the attribute selector value is a number. Even simple numeric ID selectors (like `#22`) for valid HTML5 IDs [do not work with `querySelector` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270787/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-queryselector-on-document).

Wrapping the attribute selector's value with quotes solves the issue: `'div[data-id="7821549"]'`