# How to pass dynamic id and hence dynamic toggler to UncontrolledCollapse tag of Reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Reactstrap Uncontrolled Collapse doesn't take template string!

```
{
    state.data.map(datum => {
        return (
            <>
                <Card id={`toggler${datum._id}`} className="mb-1 shadow-sm" >
                   <CardBody>
                       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: datum.faqHeading }} /> 
                   </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <UncontrolledCollapse toggler=`toggler${datum._id}`>
                    <Card>
                        <CardBody  >
                            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: datum.faqBody }} />
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </UncontrolledCollapse>
            </>
        )
    })
}
```

Or is there any other way to achieve it?
The data is coming from an API. Depending on that data (number of cards), Cards will be rendered!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap it in `{}` when you are in scope of JSX e.g., `` prop={`${variable}-some-other-string`} ``

However, I think you would also want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270787/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-queryselector-on-document). It seems Reactstrap actually makes use of `querySelectorAll`, so if you have just numbers for your `id` & `toggler` (which I suspect you have), it won't work. You need to make sure your `datum._id` contains at least an alphabet letter as its first character and not a number. After fulfilling that prerequisite, the below syntax should suffice:

```
toggler={datum._id}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data coming from the `API` will be possibly an array `[{},{},{}]` of objects. If you have control over the data that is getting returned from the `API` you can add a unique string to use for an id. By this way you can discard the use of template literals and use a simple `id`

I think `datum._id` is coming as a document from `mongodb`. Don't use `_id` to distinguish the cards in your case, Instead set an id for each object depending upon the card type and then use it. For example your own `id` instead of `_id` of mongodb.

```
<Card>
  <CardBody>
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: datum.faqBody }}/>
  </CardBody>
</Card>
```

**Secondly**, I can see that you're using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Improper use of this feature can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack because what you're doing is that `datum.faqBody` which is coming from the api can have a `script` tag containing some malicious code can execute on your website leading to `XSS` attack. Make sure you call some santizing function for `HTML` before setting it like this.

```
function createMarkup() {
  // Purify HTML here and return 
};

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Library for DOM purification : [DOM Purify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)