# Removing elements with unique IDs in firebase/firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `<div>` set up that I want to add/remove using a Firestore listener. All my documents in my collection have a unique Firestore-generated ID.

The user can press the X button on the element to remove that element from the database whilst also removing it from the frontend.

Everything works, HOWEVER whilst testing I noticed that SOMETIMES

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '[data-id = 9NrmaFNNBX1DrH940osh]' is not a valid selector.

It works perfectly fine but just randomly (or so I feel since it works half the time but out of the blue just throws me that error).

The code associated with that error message is this:

```
if (book.type ==="removed") {
    let removedCard = mainContent.querySelector(`[data-id = ${uniqueID}]`);
    mainContent.removeChild(removedCard);
}
```

When I refresh, it works perfectly fine on the same element. But especially after deleting multiple elements in a row it happens almost 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason why this is happening randomly is because of how the `querySelector` works in JavaScript. According to this [SO Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270787/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-queryselector-on-document) and the querySelector [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), `querySelector` uses CSS selectors to grab the elements on the DOM, which can't start with digits.

Looking at your ID there, `9NrmaFNNBX1DrH940osh`, and knowing that Firebase (usually) generates these ID's with random strings and digits, you're probably just running into issues where some Firebase ID's start with a digit, and others start with letters, which would make them valid.

One potential solution that I can think of for this, that I've done in the past, is to combine another attribute of your item in the database, with that ID, and use that as the `data-id` attribute. That way, they always start with letters and will always be valid. For example, something like:

```js
function itemId(item) { // item here is your firebase document
  return `${item.name}-${item.id}`
}
```

And use that value inside of your HTML instead.

Another (easier) solution thanks to @samthecodingman: you can also prefix `id-` to your `data-id` attribute in front of the Firestore document ID, and that would also make this CSS selector valid.

Comment: I'd argue it's just simpler to prefix with a single underscore `_` or some standard static string like `id-`, then if you need to do something with the ID, you know what you need to trim from it.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's probably a lot easier. Good idea

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks guys! probs shoulda noticed but that just went over my head.