# Reactstrap tooltip: Cannot set dynamic id and target: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '5f54e5d61ec2c635f81f0e6a'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am rendering a component multiple times, and each time I pass a different userId:

```
  render() {
    const { userId } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={userId} />
        <UncontrolledTooltip target={userId}>tooltip</UncontrolledTooltip>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document':
> '5f54e5d61ec2c635f81f0e68' is not a valid selector.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270787/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-queryselector-on-document)

Comment: From the error message you seem to have `userId` set to a value starting with a digit. The uncontrolled tooltip apparently uses `document.querySelectorAll` under the hood which takes a css selector which can't start with a digit.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden That solved my problem indeed. Thank you.